# How to copy a binary data vector to a float vector instead of saving as file by ofstream.write?

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++, and I got a memory buffer input as `const std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer`.

Original code use:

```
   std::ofstream os(path, std::ofstream::binary);
   for ( auto it = buffer.begin() + batchIndex * batchChunk; it != buffer.begin() + (batchIndex+1) * batchChunk; ++it )
   {
      uint8_t u = *it;
      os.write((char*)(&u), sizeof(uint8_t))

   }
```

to save the data to a file. In which `batchIndex = 0` and `batchChunk = 4000`(it's weird that the actual length of data should be 1000, float, and it do like this when I read the file by numpy in python).

I want to save such binary data into a vector instead of saving it as a file, here is what I did:

```
  std::vector<float> vec;
  vec.resize(batchChunk);
  std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.begin() + (batchIndex+1) * batchChunk, std::back_inserter(vec));
```

Then I got a vector at the length of 4000, and full of int numbers (should be length of 1000 with floats).

Please leave your advice! Thanks you so much.

Comment: Well if `batchChunk` is equal to `4000`, then that `resize` call will quite naturally set the size to `4000`. Now if you think a little, you know that each batch is `batchChunk` bytes, and you know the size of `float` in bytes (`sizeof(float)`), then how would you get how many `float` values there are in each batch?

Comment: _"Then I got a vector at the length of 4000, **and full of int numbers** [...]"_ I really doubt it. This is a `std::vector<float>`, it can only contain `float` values. Since the value are taken from an integral type (`uint8_t`), you probably have all your decimal parts equal to zero, but keep in mind that `2.0` is still a `float` or `double`, not an `int` :)

Comment: As for the copying, you copy each byte into the destination vector as its own value, instead of collecting the bytes needed to form the `float` values. So e.g. the bytes `2`, `3`, `4` and `5` will become the four floating point values `2.0`, `3.0`, `4.0` and `5.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is that `float` is 4 bytes in your case, that is 4 times the size of `uint8_t`.

So you should not resize with `batchChunk` but with `batchChunk/sizeof(float)` instead (you may directly use `buffer.size()` instead of `batchChunk`).

That being said, since you use a `std::back_inserter`, you should not `resize()` otherwise you'll get twice the size since `std::back_inserter` inserts elements.
On the other hand, you may use `reserve()` instead in order to avoid unnecessary reallocations since you already know the final size of the container. This is not mandatory though.

The second thing is that you actually construct each `float` value from a single `uint8_t` value. Hence the wrong value in output. You don't want to "cast" `uint8_t` to `float`, **you want/need to reconstruct each float from the 4 corresponding `uint8_t` values**.

The easiest way of doing it is to treat the `std::vector<uint8_t>` as if it was composed of `float` values <strike>by using `reinterpret_cast`</strike>.
You may also iterate over your container 4 by 4 and recreate each float one by one before pushing them back into the destination vector, but you lose the conciseness of using `std::copy`.

Your example can be rewritten as follows:

```
std::vector<float> vec;
vec.reserve(buffer.size()/sizeof(float)); // Optional (only to avoid unnecessary reallocations)

float * tmp = reinterpret_cast<float*>(buffer.data()); // maybe illegal (see the edit below)
std::copy(tmp, tmp + buffer.size()/sizeof(float), std::back_inserter(vec));
```

---

**Edit**

I suspect the above solution to break the strict aliasing rule (not sure if `reinterpret_cast<float*>(uint8_t*)` is legal).

A better and safer way to perform the deserialization would be to get rid of `std::copy` and use [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) instead (arguments are taken as `void*`).

We could then rewrite the solution as:

```
std::vector<float> vec(buffer.size()/sizeof(float));
std::memcpy(vec.data(), buffer.data(), buffer.size());;
```

It is even shorter and consequently clearer.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you so muuuuuch!